# Why is displacement ,instead of position, the integral of velocity?

Tags: calculus, physics

Why is the term displacement used as being the integral of velocity instead of position. The integral should cancel the derivative.

Comment: "Position" requires an assignment of coordinates in advance. Displacement is relative to the starting points.

Comment: What's the difference between displacement and position, in this context?

Comment: "The integral should cancel the derivative." Tell me again what $\int_a^b f'(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is. Is it just $f(b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the simple differential equation that relates the instantaneous position vector $s(t)$ to the velocity vector $v(t)$:

$v(t) = \frac{ds(t)}{dt}$

Integrating both sides and taking bounds gives:

$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}v(t)dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{ds(t)}{dt}dt$

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives:

$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}v(t)dt = s(t_2) - s(t_1)$

A study of the right hand side should reveal that it is the *difference* between the position vectors at time $t_2$ ("final") and time $t_1$ ("initial"), and that is *by definition* the *displacement* the particle has undergone between those two time points. And this is why the displacement is related to the integral of velocity with respect to time.

Comment: So say when you take bounds time 1 is equal to 0(the origin) would this be a case where position = displacement?

Comment: @Kyle Only provided the particle starts at the origin of the coordinate system, i.e. that $s(0) =  0$. In a lot of cases, this can be assumed, but not always (look at the given conditions in the problem).